# structにobjc_setAssociatedObjectとobjc_getAssociatedObjectでプロパティを生やすことはできないのでしょうか？

Tags: swift

```
private var associatedObjectHandle = "hogeHandle"

struct Hoge {}

extension Hoge {
    var foo: Double? {
        get {
            guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &associatedObjectHandle) as? Double else {
                return nil
            }
            return value
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(
                self,
                &associatedObjectHandle,
                newValue,
                .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
            )
        }
    }
}
```

このように foo プロパティを struct に生やそうとしましたが結果は nil です。

```
var h = Hoge()
h.foo = 5.0
print(h.foo)  // nil
```

Hogeをstructではなくてclassに変えると `Optional(5.0)` が表示されるのですが、自動生成された struct にプロパティを生やしたいので、classに変えることができません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> structにobjc_setAssociatedObjectとobjc_getAssociatedObjectでプロパティを生やすことはできないのでしょうか？

## できません。

Swiftの class で、`objc_setAssociatedObject`で`objc_getAssociatedObject`が使えるのは、

- Swiftの class の基底クラス(言語仕様上は存在しないことになっている)は、実は`NSObject`を継承している
- `NSObject`には AssociatedObject を保持するための隠しスロットがある

と言う事実に基づいています。

Swiftの struct と言うのは、そのような隠しスロットなどは持たず、C言語のstructのように、宣言されたメンバーがヒープなどを使わず直接メモリ上に展開されるので、AssociatedObject を保持するような場所がそもそもありません。

---

Objective-C側で`id`型として宣言されている引数にSwiftのstructを渡すと、内部的には`NSObject`を継承している謎クラス`__SwiftValue`のインスタンスが作成されるのですが、このようなインスタンスはstructを渡す度に再生成されるので、`objc_setAssociatedObject`でAssociatedObjectを持たせることに成功しても、そのオブジェクトはすぐに捨てられてしまい、次に`objc_getAssociatedObject`が呼ばれるとAssociatedObjectなんて持っていない新しい`__SwiftValue`のインスタンスが作成される、と言うことになります。

そもそも、Swiftの実行時処理がObjective-C非依存のプラットフォームでは`objc_getAssociatedObject`や`objc_setAssociatedObject`なんかの「Objective-Cの実行時処理関連関数」は使えないので、たとえ class であっても、それらに依存していると、移植性が損なわれるなんてことになります。